# Devise testing expired reset token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I need some help here

I'm testing weather a expired `reset_password_token` should update or not a user account. I'm setting `reset_password_sent_at` attribute in `User` model to a expired value, but the user's password are been updated anyway. I'm using Devise's recoverable module.

factories/user.rb

```
factory :user_expired_unconfirmed_password do
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  password { default_password }
  password_confirmation { default_password }
  confirmed_at { 2.days.ago }
  reset_password_token { nil }
  reset_password_sent_at { nil }
  updated_at { 2.hours.ago }
end
```

passwords_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe Devise::PasswordsController, type: :request do
  it "creater users with expired reset_password_token (6 hours max.) shouldn't update password" do
    user = FactoryBot.create(:user_expired_unconfirmed_password)
    reset_password_token = user.send_reset_password_instructions

    old_passw = user.encrypted_password
    new_passw = 'test_new_passw_123'

    # expire token
    user.reset_password_sent_at = 7.hours.ago

    #### debbug ###
    # user.reload # if uncommented, got true in the below line
    puts user.reset_password_period_valid? # got false

    put user_password_path,
      :params => {
        "user" => {
          "reset_password_token" => reset_password_token,
          "password" => new_passw,
          "password_confirmation" => new_passw
        }
      }

    expect(user.reload.encrypted_password).to eq old_passw # got false here
  end
end
```

P.s: Using the method `reset_password_period_valid?` I got `false` and `true` if I reload the user, but independent of that it's not passing the assertion.

Any idea what would be? I tested these helpers methods in Model tests with valid and expire `reset_password_token` to change the password and it worked right.

Comment: I assume it's because you're never actually saving the user after you modified the `reset_password_sent_at`. (This is way `user.reset_password_period_valid?` gives `true` or `false` after you reload the user). I would think that Devise in its controller actions perform a query to retrieve the user by the `reset_password_token`  (so they also do a  "reload" like in your test), and since the value of `reset_password_sent_at` was not saved it is valid and updated the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving the user with the new value of the `reset_password_token`

```
RSpec.describe Devise::PasswordsController, type: :request do
  it "creater users with expired reset_password_token (6 hours max.) shouldn't update password" do
    user = FactoryBot.create(:user_expired_unconfirmed_password)
    reset_password_token = user.send_reset_password_instructions

    # expire token
    user.reset_password_sent_at = 7.hours.ago
    user.save

    #### debbug ###
    user.reload
    puts user.reset_password_period_valid? # You should get false

    old_passw = user.encrypted_password
    new_passw = 'test_new_passw_123'

    put user_password_path,
      :params => {
        "user" => {
          "reset_password_token" => reset_password_token,
          "password" => new_passw,
          "password_confirmation" => new_passw
        }
      }

    expect(user.reload.encrypted_password).to eq old_passw # got false here
   end
end
```

Comment: I will try it later and post here the feedback. thanks!

Comment: It works! nice catch! I thought that `reload` would be enough, apparently it's not. Thank you for helping!